# Data protection laws and regulation for storing IP addresses for registered users

Tags: web-application, privacy, ip

I have a website, large amounts of this site can only be accessed if the user logs in. I would like to use the users IP addresses as a means to determine where they are when they access certain pages.

I would like to use the users IP to determine if they are at a certain institute (company, university, school etc.). I know the IP address ranges for the institute (e.g. `0.0.1.0` to `0.0.1.255`) and I know the users IP address e.g. `0.0.1.1`.

Ideally I would store the users IP address in a database which would enable me to say "Person X accessed page Y from computer `0.0.1.1`".

I have read, on various forums, that there are some things you need to be careful of when storing IP addresses which can be linked to specific users. In some cases people say they must be deleted after 90 days, I would like to avoid deleting this information until the user is no longer registered with my site.

Can I store this information without breaching any laws or data protection acts etc?

To summarise:

- I would like to store IP addresses for known users every time they access certain pages
- I would never store IP addresses for visitors who are not registered with my site
- The information would be stored until the user is no longer registered with the site (at which point the IPs will be deleted).
- I'm sure laws vary from country to country so for clarity: all registered users are in the UK (the data is also stored in the UK)

Comment: A workaround I could use is to check if the users IP is within the address range provided and store this as a Boolean. This would enable me to check if they were at the given institution without storing any IPs. This, for various reasons, isn't ideal but is the approach I will take if it becomes too tricky to store the users IP addresses for extended periods of time.

Comment: FYI: "The information would be stored until the user is no longer registered with the site (at which point the IPs will be deleted)." - either this is untrue as stated, or you don't have any backups with reasonable retention periods.  Set as "deleted" from the active storage, I'll believe - if you're very, very careful, I'll even buy "wiped" and perhaps "sanitized" from the active storage (i.e. disk space was overwritten - properly, if sanitized).  Your backups, particularly offsite backups?  That's much, much harder.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.  You should ask a qualified attorney for legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

European data protection law is (currently) based on the [95/46 EU directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:31995L0046%3aen%3aHTML). This means  law is mostly the same across member states in general principles (as opposed to a regulation, a EU directive gives the member states some margin on how they implement the directive while still being legally binding).

IP addresses are generally considered to be personal data within the EU, UK is exceptional in this regard. Even within the UK the ICO is aware of the fact that IP addresses are a gray area concerning personal data (good article [here](http://www.out-law.com/page-8060)) as they can be related to a unique individual without too much effort depending on who collects them.

A few data protection principles to help you decide if this is the case:

Do you store the data for one specific, lawful purpose? You mention "I want to know where they are when they access data". Why do you want to know? To sell the data gathered to a marketing firm or to optimize your site? The first may not be lawful, the second seems quite reasonable.

Is it proportional? Do you need the information you gather or could you do with less to achieve your purpose?

How long do you need the data? This depends largely on the purpose for which you gathered it in the first place. Usually there is not one defined term, it depends on the purpose. For optimizing your site 90 days could be fine, to perform a 2 year scientific analysis part of a university study on on web site usage within the UK it is not long enough.

Also, whether people registered or not does not necessarily matter as long as people give consent. Of course, the easiest way to ask for consent to process certain information is on the registration form. Data protection law requires informed consent (e.g., people saying "I agree" without actually reading the terms because the terms are font size 3 and displayed in a color similar to the background does not usually lead to informed consent). If such consent is given and you process the data you gather according to the terms you specified when people consented you should be good to go.

Final note: security is an important aspect, all personal data should be stored according to appropriate technological and organizational means. I.e., take reasonable precautions to secure the data.

Comment: In response to the data protection principles you mentioned:
I do store the data for one specific, lawful, purpose. I want to know where they are are to optimize the site, definitely not for marketing purposes in any regard. The information will never be sold or transfered to anyone. I don't think the data I collect is disproportional, I don't collect any excessive information. I need the data as long as the user is registered, this could well be a number of years. People have already agreed to allowing me to store their information.

Comment: That last part is quite important, how did they agree? A small checkmark on the registration form or did it mention which information you were collecting for which purpose? If the latter is the case, it seems quite unlikely you are going to breach data protection laws.

Comment: Btw, I just saw your comment on the other answer: since you store the name you store PII. Regardless of the IP, data protection laws are very much applicable.

Comment: I guess it shows how well-meaning(?) legislators can really goof things up and include a vague and meaningless "PII" in a law. Idiots.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check both European and UK Data protection laws to be sure, but as long as you don't collect and store [Personally Identifiable Information (PII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information), you won't have to really bother with laws and regulations.

More precisely:

> An IP address in isolation is not personal data under the UK Data
>   Protection Act, according to the Information Commissioner. But an IP
>   address can become personal data when combined with other information
>   or when used to build a profile of an individual, even if that
>   individual's name is unknown.

So this has to be determined based on the type of information you collect and/or store from your users.

Also, as mentionned into comments this does not seems like the right approach to achieve this.

Comment: According to the link you provided I do store a few pieces of PII. These are: first and last name, email address and Name of the school they attend or workplace.
Could you expand on your last comment: "...this does not seems like the right approach to achieve this". The comment by @Anti-weakpasswords seems to address the issue of removing data with regards to backups not the approach as a whole.